# How to ignore an event until the other same type event is completed in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

I want you to assume an extremely basic situation where if you hover over a slider, it slightly enlarges and then goes back to its original size when you leave its surface. Here is the code:

```
def enterEvent(self,event):
    self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"geometry")
    self.anim.setDuration(200)
    if self.anim.state() == self.anim.State.Stopped:
        rectt = self.geometry()
        self.anim.setStartValue(rectt)
        rectt += QMargins(10,10,10,10)
        self.anim.setEndValue(rectt)
        self.anim.start()

def leaveEvent(self, event):
    if self.anim.state() == self.anim.State.Stopped:
        self.anim.setDirection(self.anim.Backward)
        self.anim.start()
    QSlider.leaveEvent(self,event)
```

The problem is if you hover over it fast enough, it gets bigger then does not go back to the  original size. And, if you keep doing that it continuously enlarges. I do not know why that happens. I already used an if condition to check whether the animation is stopped or running  and that statement clearly do not works properly. Is there any way to wait for accepting the next event until the ongoing one is completed.

Comment: You're constantly creating a *new* animation in the `enterEvent`, which obviously will always be in the `Stopped` state at that point. Create the animation in the `__init__` and keep using it. Also restore the animation direction.

Comment: That actually is so clever, I really wonder why I have not thought about this before. It worked perfectly but for further clarification for others, pay attention to where you place the **setDirection** method. Because if you place **setDirection(self.anim.Forward)** in the **enterEvent()**, the problem will not be fixed and the slider will continuously grow. You should place the **Forward** notation in the def __init__ function and for the **"Backward"** notation in the **leaveEvent()**. @musicamante You have my thanks, appreciated...

Comment: You're welcome. But, no, you *must* set the direction in the `enterEvent()`, otherwise the animation will only run once. The problem is that you should only update the start/end value *if* the animation is stopped, but *then* always set the direction and start it, no matter the current state.

Comment: But now I did it in the way I wrote in the comment and it works perfectly fine. In contrary, when I set the direction in the enterEvent(), the problem occurs again and the slider perpetually grows. Maybe you are right, there is a possibility that somethings in my setup is weird and that is why it works for me in the way I mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @musicamante explained, what I was doing wrong is defining the animation in the enterEvent() which results in a constant animation creation everytime you hover the mouse over the button. Solution is replacing the animation definition outside of the enterEvent() function, to the init function.